# Имена в NS-записях вместо адресов - неприятная особенность DNS

Tags: dns

Чтобы разобраться в работе DNS, я попытался написать простой resolver без кэша, который бы мог выполнять рекурсивные запросы, начиная с корневых серверов. Возникла проблема: если сервер не располагает запрашиваемыми данными, то он возвращает нам в Authority-секции NS-записи с именами тех серверов, которые "ближе к ответу", **но он не обязан возвращать A-записи в Additional-секции, соотв. NS-записям в Authority-секции**. Он просто может не знать адреса этих серверов - не обязан. Они могут быть не в его зоне. Исключение - glue-записи.

Таким образом, что получается: имеем имя, адрес которого мы должны получить. Обращаемся к одному из корневых серверов (его адрес мы берём из конфига). Он нам возвращает **имена** серверов, которые "ближе к ответу" (вероятно, это те, зона которых включает Top-Level- Domain). А вот адресов их он нам не сообщает. Пусть и сообщит, но на следующей итерации - один из этих серверов сообщит нам **имя** сервера "ближе к ответу", но не его адрес. Т.о. у нас на руках будет уже 2 имени, адреса которых нужно получить, причём адрес первого мы не получим не зная адреса второго. Будем пытаться получить адрес 2-ого, получим ещё одно имя. Рекурсия, чёрт! Как бы всё было проще, если бы в NS-записях был адрес, а не имя. Но нет, в теории по любому имени с помощью системы DNS мы можем получить сооотв. адрес, но на практике это усложняет процесс.

Вопрос: почему в NS-записях содержится имя, а не адрес? Разве так часто меняются адреса DNS-серверов, что сложно обновлять файл зоны? Удобство здесь маленький плюс, по сравнению с усложнением всей схемы.
Почему эта рекурсия (которую описал) вообще конечна?

P.S: знаю, что поэкспериментировав, выполняя вручную последовательные запросы, м.б. я бы разобрался в чём тут дело, но руки не доходят. Может кому ещё будет полезно мой комментарий/замечание по системе DNS.

Answer (score 1):

> почему в NS-записях содержится имя, а не адрес?

потому что именно так изложено в [rfc1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#page-18).

это даёт определённую гибкость и обратную совместимость: например, даже в рамках той же *arpanet* не так давно была добавлена совершенно иная схема адресов, и у *a resource record* появилось «дополнение» в виде *aaaa resource record*. а ведь (в принципе) на *arpanet* свет клином не сошёлся, и добавление новых схем адресации легко впишется в текущую реализацию протокола.

**дополнение про масштабируемость**

одно и то же имя может «обслуживаться» произвольным количеством физических устройств:

```
$ dig -t a ya.ru
;ya.ru.             IN  A
ya.ru.          5833    IN  A   93.158.134.3
ya.ru.          5833    IN  A   213.180.193.3
ya.ru.          5833    IN  A   213.180.204.3
```

**дополнение про расширяемость**

одно и то же имя может «обслуживаться» физическими устройствами, доступными из разных сетей:

```
$ dig -t aaaa ya.ru
;ya.ru.             IN  AAAA
ya.ru.          22  IN  AAAA    2a02:6b8::3
```

**дополнение про совместимость**

когда в будущем возникнет необходимость адресовать физические устройства в какой-нибудь совершенно новой сети, в протоколе не нужно будет **ничего менять**. достаточно будет всего лишь **добавить** ещё один тип записи:

```
$ dig -t xyz ya.ru
...
```

Comment: **потому что именно так изложено в rfc1035** - спасибо, посмеялся. А если серьёзно: нет проблем, пусть тогда формат NS-записи (RDATA) был бы такой: <тип адресации> <адрес>.

Comment: @cucaracha, *пусть тогда* — ни малейших проблем! в вашей собственной сети вы можете отказаться и от совместимости и от расширяемости и от масштабируемости.